# Using CiviRules to create a Case on a Contact record

Tags: wordpress, civicase, civirules

I'm trying to use CiviRules in WordPress to create a new Case for contact records using a Field Value Comparison (when a custom data field "is not empty").

My test cases are confirming that the rule is executing and certain other rule Actions are being applied (e.g. adding the contact to a Group), but the Case is not being created on the Contact record.

There is a log entry that is added each time the rule executes that I believe is related to why the Case is not being created, but I am not sure how to interpret it.

It's an error message that says Rule: 'Test Rule' with id xx failed for contact xxxxx because of Failed to execute action.

For more detail, here is the Context section of the error message:

```
(
    [rule_title] => Test Rule
    [original_error] => Civirules could not fund case: Expected one Case but found 0. API call: Case.getsingle with params: contact_id="xxxx", case_type_id="3", status_id="1"
    [reason] => Failed to execute action
)
```

Any insight that can be provided about places to look for additional information or things I possibly may not have configured properly would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello, Rainer. Did you ever get a resolution to this issue? I've encountered the exact same error as you.

Answer (score 1):

I would debug the Field Value Comparison (class CRM_CivirulesConditions_Generic_ValueComparison and function isConditionValid) to check if the condition is OK.

What CiviRules action are you using to create the case?